# processing xml files with bash scripting

Tags: bash, xml-parsing, sed, awk

I have an xml file which has the following structure that contains numerous `<Episodes></Episodes>` to which the structure looks like this:

```
<Episode>
  <id>4195462</id>
  <Combined_episodenumber>8</Combined_episodenumber>
  <Combined_season>2</Combined_season>
  <DVD_chapter></DVD_chapter>
  <DVD_discid></DVD_discid>
  <DVD_episodenumber></DVD_episodenumber>
  <DVD_season></DVD_season>
  <Director>Jay Karas</Director>
  <EpImgFlag>2</EpImgFlag>
  <EpisodeName>Karl's Wedding</EpisodeName>
  <EpisodeNumber>8</EpisodeNumber>
  <FirstAired>2011-11-08</FirstAired>
  <GuestStars>Katee Sackhoff|Carla Gallo</GuestStars>
  <IMDB_ID></IMDB_ID>
  <Language>en</Language>
  <Overview>Karl Hevacheck, aka the Human Genius, gets married.</Overview>
  <ProductionCode>209</ProductionCode>
  <Rating>7.6</Rating>
  <RatingCount>20</RatingCount>
  <SeasonNumber>2</SeasonNumber>
  <Writer>Kevin Etten</Writer>
  <absolute_number></absolute_number>
  <filename>episodes/211751/4195462.jpg</filename>
  <lastupdated>1362547148</lastupdated>
  <seasonid>471254</seasonid>
  <seriesid>211751</seriesid>
</Episode>
```

I've figured out how to pull the information between a single tag like so

```
  value=$(grep -m 1 "<Rating>" path_to_file | sed 's/<.*>\(.*\)<\/.*>/\1/')
```

but I can't find a way to verify that I am looking at the correct episode ie. to check If this is the correct branch which is for `<Combined_season>2</Combined_season>  <EpisodeNumber>8</EpisodeNumber>` before saving the values for specific attributes. I know this can somehow be done using a combination of sed and awk but can't seem to figure it out anyhelp on how I can do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a proper XML parser not `sed` or `awk`!

Comment: @sudo_O this function is part of a much larger bash program so i was hoping i could just use one of these... why is this such a bad idea?

Comment: You can still call your XML parser from your bash script. It's a bad idea because XML is a structured file, sed and awk typical work with line oriented files. You will just give yourself a headache by using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @sudo_O Simple enough then, I'll just use php then ... if you'd like copy to an answer and ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proper XML parser not `sed` or `awk`. You can still call your XML parser from your bash script just like you would with `sed` or `awk`. It's a bad idea to use `sed` or `awk` because XML is a structured file, `sed` and `awk` typical work with line oriented files. You will just give yourself a headache by using the wrong tool for the job. I suggest using a dedicated tools or a language such a `php`, `python` or `perl` (or any other language not starting with `p`) that has libraries for parsing XML.